# Invalid field name: Contact.Activities$What

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, migration, force.com-ide

I am using force.com IDE to migrate reports.
For a report of custom type Contacts with Activities, I get error:

> "Invalid field name: Contact.Activities$What"

The report type is already deployed to destination org.

Does anybody have a clue?